# On premise application configuration service for .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, configuration, appsettings

I am searching for an on-premise solution where I can call my application settings for my .NET Core apps from an external service like the `Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager` provides.

With this solution I want to share secrets/settings across apps and environments.